# ActionBar problems to use libs

Tags: android

incompatible types

Required: import android.app.ActionBar;
Found: import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

And why am I having to use @SuppressWarnings({"deprecation", "UnusedAssignment"}) for use  extends ActionBarActivity.

```
package com.example.matheus.bars;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;



@SuppressWarnings({"deprecation", "UnusedAssignment"})
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        android.app.ActionBar actionBar;

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(actionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
        tab.setText("Hello");


    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post your code for us to tell you why you are getting warnings.

Comment: Without additional information noone will be able to solve this question.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a couple things going on here. If you are using the support Action bar you need this:

```
// use a different import
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar;
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Then as far as the navigation and tab goes, these methods are deprecated and not used any more.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html

Comment: Ok i am using your method. More if i retired @SuppressWarnings({"deprecation", "UnusedAssignment"}) i cant use ActionBarActivity and setNavigationMode, knows whats could be causing this?

Comment: Ok. Can say me the most used and most practical methods? I'm new in the area.